# bunch of errors when launching python console

Tags: python, flask, pipenv

whenever i create project in pycharm using eny virtual environment and flask i get these errors, while launching python console :

```
 import sys
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\flaskProject', 'C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2023.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm', 'C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2023.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev'])
from flask.cli import ScriptInfo
locals().update(ScriptInfo(create_app=None).load_app().make_shell_context())
print("Python %s on %s\nApp: %s [%s]\nInstance: %s" % (sys.version, sys.platform, app.import_name, app.env, app.instance_path))
PyDev console: starting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\flaskProject-9hB4V9OB\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 313, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\flaskProject-9hB4V9OB\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 224, in locate_app
    raise NoAppException(
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing 'wsgi', an ImportError was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\flaskProject-9hB4V9OB\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'
```

i have no idea what these errors are  ,flask server runs fine .

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the error traces as code, e.g. using quotes: ``` (...) ```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `wsgi` module. Check that you have it installed in your venv